# PasswordSignInAsync. ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm using the following code to sign in a user:

```
public async Task<RepositoryResponse> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent,
    bool lockoutOnFailure)
{
    var signInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, isPersistent, lockoutOnFailure);

    return GetResponseBySignInResult(signInResult);
}
```

I'm getting an exception that originates from the `PasswordSignInAsync` method, as shown here:

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   entityType Microsoft.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value,
>   String parameterName)

I'm using Identity 3, MVC6 and Entity Framework 7.

Comment: Have you checked if you are having values for all the arguments in the Function?

Comment: None of the values are null.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this one?

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar problem that drove me nuts for ages... it's worth checking your user has a SecurityStamp that isn't null (setting it as a random string will work). Identity seems to not have a problem storing it as a null field in the database, but as soon as you need to do anything like log in it throws this exception.

That was my issue, hope it's the same for you and it works! (Despite how long ago this question was asked)

In the meantime, if anyone with more knowledge of Identity than I have stumbles across this and can explain the virtue of the SecurityStamp being nullable it might be worth an upvote or two.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, this issue was caused by the fact that my user model (the one that inherites from IdentityUser) was overriding the Id property. Removing the line `public int Id { get; set; }` from this model solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you are setting Claim value in class of ApplicationUser like below.

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FirstName", this.FirstName));
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("LastName", this.LastName));
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FullName", this.FullName));
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("MobileNo", this.PhoneNumber)); 
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Id", this.Id));
            return userIdentity;
        }
```

And value of any of them is null , So when signing it will throw this kind of exception,
Then please make sure  that values for your Claims have value in Db "AspNetUsers" Table

Thanks

Dushmantha

Comment: Thank you. I forgot that I had been messing with my database and had a null claim in there. It would be nice if they gave a more descriptive error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and I found that I had a null value in my AspNetRoleClaims table in the database for the ClaimValue column in one of the records. Once I fixed that, I was able to login.